# The useFocusEffect doesn't update setstate

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-v5

I have this useFocusEffect function:

```js
useFocusEffect(
    useCallback(() => {
        async function setFilterValue() {
            let filterValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem('filterValue');
            let inputValue = JSON.parse(filterValue);
            if (gpsFilterValue === null) {
                setGpsFilterValue(inputValue);
                console.log('null')
                // setRefreshing(true)
            } else if (inputValue !== parseInt(gpsFilterValue)) {
                setGpsFilterValue(inputValue);
                console.log('refreshing1')
                setTimeout(() => {
                    console.log(gpsFilterValue)
                }, 1000);
                //console.log(inputValue + ' ' + gpsFilterValue)
                //setRefreshing(true)
            } else {
                console.log('test')
            }
        }
        setFilterValue();
    }, [])
);
```

When I debug the gpsFilterValue in the setTimeout it stays undefined, but when I make a button in the render to debug the gpsFilterValue state value and press it, it has updated. How come the values are different?

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it `gpsFilterValue` is part of your state as you have a state setter being invoked in the callback. However, your `useCallback` isn't listing `gpsFilterValue` as a dependency (that empty array that is the second parameter to `useCallback`. Add it to that dependency list and you should see the updated value.

```
useFocusEffect(
    useCallback(() => {
        async function setFilterValue() {
            let filterValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem('filterValue');
            let inputValue = JSON.parse(filterValue);
            if (gpsFilterValue === null) {
                setGpsFilterValue(inputValue);
                console.log('null')
                // setRefreshing(true)
            } else if (inputValue !== parseInt(gpsFilterValue)) {
                setGpsFilterValue(inputValue);
                console.log('refreshing1')
                setTimeout(() => {
                    console.log(gpsFilterValue)
                }, 1000);
                //console.log(inputValue + ' ' + gpsFilterValue)
                //setRefreshing(true)
            } else {
                console.log('test')
            }
        }
        setFilterValue();
    }, [gpsFilterValue])
);
```